# Is there a way to set a different activation function for each hidden unit in one layer in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, activation-function

I'm trying to set a different activation function for each hidden unit in a layer. Is this possible in Keras with 'Concatenate'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get the point, you can use a similar code like the following:

```
from keras.layers import merge, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Input

input = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))

seq1 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(input)
seq2 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(input)
seq3 = Dense(1, activation = 'tanh')(input)

acum = merge([seq1, seq2, seq3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
```

Depending on your task, specify `concat_axis`.

Comment: how should I set "concat_axis"? I want to have all units in one layer. I read the documentation, but I didn't get much from it.

Comment: suppose you have [[1, 2], [3, 4]] and [[98, 99], [100, 101]] if your axis is 0 the rows get concatenated, if 1, the columns get concatenated.

Comment: ok, but what does the default value that is -1 mean in this case?

Comment: I don't have access to its documentation right now, but if you are familiar with numpy.reshap, whenever you specify -1 it does a default operation, which in this case it unrolls the array to reshape that as a vector if you set it as the first input if I remember.

Comment: well, the code works fine but I'm still not sure that it is doing what I want

Comment: I suggest you taking a look at the implementation of googlenet in keras, that may help you